# Fetch : Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInfo'

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch-api

Im receiving the following error in the "fetchUrl" argument in the fetch function

> Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'RequestInfo'.

In this function

```
let fetchUrl = getBaseUrlNative( process.env.APP_DATA, `/v2/marketing/app/file/${file}?cookies=${cookieSess}&expires=${Date.now()}`)

    await fetch(fetchUrl, { method: 'get' , cache:"no-store" , headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
      }})
         .then(res => res.blob())
         .then(res => {  .......
```

getBaseUrlNative is

```
export const getBaseUrlNative = (eUrl : string | undefined, ext : string | undefined) => {
    try {
        if (!eUrl) throw new Error("Error .")
        return ext ? eUrl+ext : eUrl;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use the ***any*** data type in the fetch function to disallow type checking.

```js
let fetchUrl = getBaseUrlNative( process.env.APP_DATA, `/v2/marketing/app/file/${file}?cookies=${cookieSess}&expires=${Date.now()}`)

    await fetch(<any>fetchUrl, { method: 'get' , cache:"no-store" , headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
      }})
         .then(res => res.blob())
         .then(res => {  .......
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because your env variable comes as undefined before you use it.

Use type assertion with the keyword:

> as

So something like:

```
getBaseUrlNative( process.env.APP_DATA as string, ...)
```

This should work just fine.

edit/update:

```
getBaseUrlNative( process.env.APP_DATA!, ...)
```

this should also work. by including !, we're saying we know the value would not be undefined by the time the page renders so we can ignore the warning.