# React Typescript: Property 'any' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This question is related
[Fetch : Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInfo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832885/fetch-argument-of-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of)

Im receiving the following error in the "fetchUrl" argument in the fetch function

> Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'RequestInfo'.

In this function

```
let fetchUrl = getBaseUrlNative( process.env.APP_DATA, `/v2/marketing/app/file/${file}?cookies=${cookieSess}&expires=${Date.now()}`)

    await fetch(fetchUrl, { method: 'get' , cache:"no-store" , headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
      }})
         .then(res => res.blob())
         .then(res => {  .......
```

getBaseUrlNative is

```
export const getBaseUrlNative = (eUrl : string | undefined, ext : string | undefined) => {
    try {
        if (!eUrl) throw new Error("Error .")
        return ext ? eUrl+ext : eUrl;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

First I fixed it by adding  and it works

```
let fetchUrl = getBaseUrlNative( process.env.APP_DATA, `/v2/marketing/app/file/${file}?cookies=${cookieSess}&expires=${Date.now()}`)

    await fetch(<any>fetchUrl, { method: 'get' , cache:"no-store" , headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
      }})
         .then(res => res.blob())
         .then(res => {  .......
```

But some of them give me an error when adding any

> Property 'any' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'
>
> Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'RequestInfo'.

Comment: And if you passing any directly after fetch, like this `fetch<any>(...)`?

Comment: I ended up doing let fetchUrl : any = ..... . Did the trick