# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInfo'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert existing React project from JavaScript to TypeScript. I have this function:

```
  const isSad = async (value: string) => {
    return await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_TEXT_TO_EMOTION_API, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        apikey: process.env.REACT_APP_TEXT_TO_EMOTION_API_KEY,
      },
      body: value,
    })
      .then(data => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        // Checking api response and returning true if sad or false if not.
        return data.Sad > 0.49
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("logging the error in catch", error);
      });
  };
```

Nothing is glowing red in VS Code but when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInfo'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RequestInfo'.  TS2345
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832885/fetch-argument-of-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of) solution but when I try to add `<any>` in front of `process.env` it reads it as JSX and everything turns red

Comment: Seems that error somewhere else, but not in the given code. Could you please provide the code where `RequestInfo` object being assigned?

Comment: I'm not using RequestInfo anywhere

Comment: Use the `thing as any` syntax instead of `<any>thing` - see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions. Or actually check there is a value.

Comment: @Drag13 it _is_ in the given code, `RequestInfo` is the type of the first argument to `fetch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to make sure your env variable isn't undefined before you use it.

```
const isSad = async (value: string) => {
    const apiAddress: string|undefined = process.env.REACT_APP_TEXT_TO_EMOTION_API

    if (!apiAddress) throw 'API address not defined'

    // `apiAddress` is of type string at this point
    return await fetch(apiAddress, {
    //...
```

or use a type assertion with the newer `as` keyword (since the original syntax clashes with jsx), but this is less type-safe

```
    return await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_TEXT_TO_EMOTION_API as string, {
    // ...
```